# How to determine if a GitHub project has a POM file or not?

Tags: python, ruby, maven, sorting, github

I'm a member of an organization on GitHub, which has varieties of different projects in it. I'm looking for a way to check the type a project, without actually opening it.

For example, if it is a Maven project, I want my program to return `pom.xml`, if it is a Python project, return a `requirements.txt`, and if it is a Ruby project, return `Gemfile` and so on.

Is there any way I can determine the type of the project? I tried searching online, but wasn't able to find this functionality available in any API.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I don't have an answer, unfortunately, but for a second I thought you were searching GitHub for pornography, not "pom" files...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following works with [`curl`](https://curl.haxx.se/), [`jq`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) and [`XMLStarlet`](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/). See also [GitHub API Overview](https://developer.github.com/v3/). There's also [a Ruby library to access the API](https://developer.github.com/guides/traversing-with-pagination/).

#### Organization's repositories

```
$ curl -s https://api.github.com/orgs/apache/repos?per_page=4 |  \
    jq ".[] | {project: .full_name}" 
{
  "project": "apache/tapestry3"
}
{
  "project": "apache/apr-iconv"
}
{
  "project": "apache/tapestry4"
}
{
  "project": "apache/tapestry5"
}
```

#### File existence and content (POM)

```
$ curl -s https://raw.githubusercontent.com/apache/maven/master/pom.xml_does_not_exist
404: Not Found

$ curl -s https://raw.githubusercontent.com/apache/maven/master/pom.xml |  \
  xml sel -t -o "[" -v "//_:project/_:parent/_:groupId" -o "|"  \
    -v "//_:project/_:groupId" -o "]:" -v "//_:project/_:artifactId" -o ":"  \
    -v "//_:project/_:version" -n -t -v "//_:project/_:name" -n -v "//_:project/_:description"
[org.apache.maven|]:maven:3.5.0-SNAPSHOT
Apache Maven
Maven is a software build management and
    comprehension tool. Based on the concept of a project object model:
    builds, dependency management, documentation creation, site
    publication, and distribution publication are all controlled from
    the declarative file. Maven can be extended by plugins to utilise a
    number of other development tools for reporting or the build
    process.
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I was looking to do something quite similar to this. This helped me get an idea of what I was missing with the GitHub API! :)